# Open source serverless computing framework

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I'm currently working on deploying a FaaS solution on a private distributed storage system. I've been searching for a serverless computing tool that can be deployed in custom storage backend, where data can be stored and later processed by executing some client code.

AWS seems to be the most popular option regarding serverless computing implementations. However, it's not open source.

Do you know any alternative to AWS that can be implemented on top of a proprietary storage backend? Thank you in advance for contributing.

Comment: You might find and https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk helpful. Also there is a serverless implementation see https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-v1.6.0/

Comment: You should define what `serverless` means to you. With AWS Lambda or Azure Functions you don't have to care about the machines, VMs or containers that run your scripts. With on-premise software you do. It's no longer serverless as far as *you* are concerned. It *may* appear so to application developers if you take care of all the required VM and container administration. That's a lot of infrastrucure management

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, OpenWhisk is one option, but another would be Iron.io's Functions platform which is open-source http://open.iron.io

Ultimately, many of the solutions you'll likely encounter will include the use of Docker. So you might just want to start with Docker and see how it works for you. The challenges then become orchestration for which there's a few players in the space including Kubernetes.

You may also want to look into some of the products and services Datawire offers. https://www.datawire.io

Once you're running Docker you can do pretty much whatever you want with regard to hosting. When you reach for services like AWS Lambda or ECS then you'll be a bit more stuck. However, you will need to take care of many more details yourself.